# How does this non-inverting amplifier remove the offset of the input signal?

Tags: amplifier, adc

I'm trying to find out how the circuit inside the red line works.

[image]

It seems to remove the offset of the signal V<sub>rect</sub> and amplify it.

[image]

I would like to know how exactly that works. Is it possible to limit the signal V<sub>out2</sub> at a lower voltage than V<sub>cc</sub> (Let's say I want to connect to an ADC that can only read till 3 V)?

Comment: If the resistor with no value would be 22k, like R8, it would be a differential amplifier, with one leg connected to Vrefb. The output would be the difference of the input and Vrefb . As it is, the "difference" is unbalanced depending on that resistor (which is probably trimmed or a.o.t.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic summary of what your circuit does is:

1. Integrates the signal and adds an 1.67V offset to towards vout. The 1.67V comes from vref; the voltage divider 5k/(10k+5k).

Normally, this 1.67V sees would see a non-inverting amplification towards the output by (1+R2/R1). However, since you have a series capacitor with R1, then the effective resistance at DC becomes infinite, hence the DC gain this vref voltage sees is just 1, because the R2/R1 term vanishes.

2. It is followed by a so-called peak detector (though I'd call it an amplitude detector), but I guess you know how that works.
3. To see how the difference amplifier implemented by last stage works, it's better to apply superposition to each of the inputs. This means, I'll consider each input signal (vrect and vrefb) one at a time, while considering the other input signal to be ground or 0V.

vrect transfer towards the output:

$$ v_{out2,vrect} = \frac{R_5}{R_6 + R_5}\left(1+\frac{R_8}{R_7}\right) $$

vrefb transfer towars the output:

$$ v_{out2,vrefb} = -\frac{R_8}{R_7} $$

That means, we have the following output:

$$ v_{out2} = v_{out2,vrect} + v_{out2,vrefb} = vrect\frac{R_5}{R_6 + R_5}\left(1+\frac{R_8}{R_7}\right) - vrefb\frac{R_8}{R_7} $$

As you can see, the 2nd term, being vrefb a DC signal, it subtracts an scaled version of vrefb from your vrect signal.

Based on your values, your R5 & R6 voltage divider gives a factor 0.82 = 22k/(4.7k+22k) and is multiplied by 5.68 (1+22k/4.7k), which gives a total gain of 4.68 towards the output.

If you would like accommodate this signal to an smaller supply, then you can size your R5 & R6 voltage divider such that your signal is smaller towards the output.